# bc scale: How to avoid rounding? (Calculate small binomial probability)

Tags: numeric-data, bc, calculator

Following code calculates the Binomial Probability of a success event k out of n trials:

```
n=144
prob=$(echo "0.0139" | bc)

echo -e "Enter no.:" 
read passedno

k=$passedno
nCk2() {
    num=1
    den=1
    for((i = 1; i <= $2; ++i)); do
        ((num *= $1 + 1 - i)) && ((den *= i))
    done
    echo $((num / den))
}

binomcoef=$(nCk2 $n $k)

binprobab=$(echo "scale=8; $binomcoef*($prob^$k)*((1-$prob)^($n-$k))" | bc)

echo $binprobab
```

When for $passedno (=k) "5" is entered, then the result is shown as 0 (instead of "0.03566482") whereas with "4" passed I get ".07261898".

**How can I print the output with given precision of 8 decimal digits without getting the rounded value of the output?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW,

```
prob=$(echo "0.0139" | bc)
```

is unnecessary - you can just do

```
prob=0.0139
```

Eg,

```
$ prob=0.0139; echo "scale=5;1/$prob" | bc
71.94244
```

---

There's another problem with your code, apart from the underflow issue. Bash arithmetic may not be adequate to handle the large numbers in your `nCk2` function. Eg, on a 32 bit system passing 10 to that function returns a *negative* number, -133461297271.

To handle the underflow issue you need to calculate at a larger scale, as mentioned in the other answers. For the parameters given in the OP a scale of 25 to 30 is adequate.

I've re-written your code to do all the arithmetic in `bc`. Rather than just piping commands into `bc` via `echo`, I've written a full `bc` script as a [*here* document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) inside a Bash script, since that makes it easy to pass parameters from Bash to `bc`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Binomial probability calculations using bc
# Written by PM 2Ring 2015.07.30

n=144
p='1/72'
m=16
scale=30

bc << EOF
define ncr(n, r)
{
    auto v,i

    v = 1
    for(i=1; i<=r; i++)
    {
        v *= n--
        v /= i
    }
    return v
}

define binprob(p, n, r)
{
    auto v

    v = ncr(n, r)
    v *= (1 - p) ^ (n - r)
    v *= p ^ r
    return v
}

sc = $scale
scale = sc
outscale = 8

n = $n
p = $p
m = $m

for(i=0; i<=m; i++)
{
    v = binprob(p, n, i)
    scale = outscale
    print i,": ", v/1, "\n"
    scale = sc
}
EOF
```

**output**

```
0: .13345127
1: .27066174
2: .27256781
3: .18171187
4: .09021610
5: .03557818
6: .01160884
7: .00322338
8: .00077747
9: .00016547
10: .00003146
11: .00000539
12: .00000084
13: .00000012
14: .00000001
15: 0
16: 0
```

Answer (score 6):

#### The Intro

Say you want to calculate what percentage 7 is of 116.
You simply divide 7 by 116 and multiply the result by 100.
It should go something like this:

[image]

```
bc -l <<< '(7/116)*100'
6.03448275862068965500
```

---

#### The Problem

You want it accurate to two decimal places so you add `scale=2;`, expecting this:

[image]
But you get some strange results:

```
bc -l <<< 'scale=2; 100*(7/116)'
6.00
```

You try increasing the `scale` value:

```
bc -l <<< 'scale=3; 100*(7/116)'
6.000
```

For some reason `scale=4;` is accurate to 2 places, but has these trailing `0`s

```
bc -l <<< 'scale=4; 100*(7/116)'
6.0300
```

---

#### The Reason

The first part of the calculation is accurate to 2 decimal places and the rest gets chopped off.
[image]
[image]

---

#### The Solution

The ideal solution would be for `bash`/`sh` to support floating point calculations natively. Why don't they already? I have no idea. Seems stupid not to. Until then you can make do with these:

**bc**

1. Define a variable.
2. Set the `scale`.
3. Divide by 1.

```
bc -l <<< "x=(7/116)*100; scale=2; x/1"
6.03
```

**printf**

1. Wrap the `bc` command with `"$(`...`)"` for command substitution.
2. Pass it to `printf`.
3. Use `%.2f` in the format string (`%f` says float, `.2` says accurate to 2 decimal places (like `scale=2`)).

```
printf '%.2f\n' "$(bc -l <<< '(7/116)*100')"
6.03
```

**awk**

1. FYI: `awk` can do arithmetic too
2. I think `echo` breaks the interactive loop somehow. There's probably a better way to do it.
3. It doesn't give you control over the floating point. I'm sure it can be done though somehow.

```
echo | awk '{print 100*(7/116)}'
6.03448
```

Comment: as for the last solution (awk), you don't have to use "echo" if you prepend the expression with "BEGIN", and you can also control the floating point by using printf instead of print:

awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n", 100*(7/116)}'

Answer (score 1):

```
n=144
prob=$(echo "0.0139" | bc)

echo -e "Enter no.:"
read passedno

k=$passedno
nCk2() {
    num=1
    den=1
    for((i = 1; i <= $2; ++i)); do
        ((num *= $1 + 1 - i)) && ((den *= i))
    done
    echo $((num / den))
}

binomcoef=$(nCk2 $n $k)
binprobab=$(echo "$binomcoef*($prob^$k)*((1-$prob)^($n-$k))" | bc -l)
printf "%0.8f\n" $binprobab
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know it's because `0.0139^5 = .00000000051888844699` is too small and rounded to 0 with `scale=8`.  How about doing intermediate calculations with greater scale, then round the last value with `scale=8`?

```
binprobab=$(echo "scale=20; a=$binomcoef*($prob^$k)*((1-$prob)^($n-$k)); scale=8; a/1" | bc)
```

Dividing by 1 is commonly used to round a number with `scale` in bc.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the explanation @voices.
The awk solution with printf:

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf("%.2f\n",100*7/116)}'
```

Comment: This answer is not even touching on `bc`, which was the topic of the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I should use reply to voices, becouse his awk 3 solution is not perfect. I am a newbie :P

Comment: @jesse_b: it's not > but <, awk wants input, maybe there is a switch to disable it, but it was simplier :P

Comment: @Kusalananda: I don't have enogh reputation to comment. lol. I just tried to help others. well. fork.

Comment: @jesse_b: my bad. it really doesn't. thanks